# ActionbarSherlock Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer

I am trying to change the TextViews in ActionBarSherlock Navigation drawer to EditTexts with hints.
so far i have accomplished to create edit texts from it (which was piece a cake) but i cannot seem to find out how to create a Hint from the text, it appears as filled in editTexts now..

how can i change it?
Below is my code.
As i do not know which part is relevant, i post a lot of code.

```
mFragmentTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);
    //mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, mFragmentTitles));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
            mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,
            R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close){
        public void onDrawerClosed(View v){
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
        public void onDrawerOpened(View v){
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        selectItem(0);
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
   return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case android.R.id.home:
        if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)){
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
        return true;
    case R.id.settings:
        if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)){
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id){
        selectItem(position);
    }
}
private void selectItem(int position){
    Fragment newFragment = new Fragment_1();
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    switch(position){
    case 0:
        newFragment = new Fragment_1();
        break;
    case 1:
        newFragment = new fragment_2();
        break;
    case 2:
        newFragment = new fragment_3();
        break;
    case 3:
        newFragment = new fragment_4();
        break;
    case 4:
        newFragment = new Fragment_1();
        break;
    }
    fm.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment)
    .commit();

    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mFragmentTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title){
    mTitle = title;
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

}
```

In my Xml is an EditText (drawer_list_item.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:textColor="#fff"
android:minHeight="48dp"/>
```

and this is my other XML which i use to display the drawer.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawer" >
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"/>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="#0c7f58"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:background="#13ca8c"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image: like so]

Comment: Please post the part where you set the EditText's hint.

Comment: That is exactly my question, where do i do that.

Comment: But where is the EditText? Is it in a layout xml file? Or do you create it programmatically (in Java code)? Because it's not in these snippets :) Please post that part.

Comment: @matiash its posted, in the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way to fix this is to create a custom MenuAdapter and put the edit texts in there.

```
mMenuAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(MainFragActivity.this, title);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mMenuAdapter);
```

//In your main class put the above code, then in your custom class put the below code;

---

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MenuListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

// Declare variables
Context context;
String[] mTitle;
String[] mSubTitle;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public MenuListAdapter(Context context, String[] title) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mTitle = title;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mTitle.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mTitle[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Declare Variables
    EditText txtTitle;
    TextView txtSubTitle;
    ImageView imgIcon;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, parent, false);

    // Locate the TextViews
    txtTitle = (EditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    // Set the data
    txtTitle.setHint(mTitle[position]);
    txtTitle.setBackground(null);

    return itemView;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

An `ArrayAdapter`, by default, loads the string value of each item as the corresponding `TextView`'s text. It's implementation of `getView()` is:

```
    if (convertView == null) {
        view = mInflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }

    <irrelevant stuff snipped>

    T item = getItem(position);
    if (item instanceof CharSequence) {
        text.setText((CharSequence)item);
    } else {
        text.setText(item.toString());
    }
```

If what you want to do is load the hint instead of the text, you should override this method. For example, as this:

```
EditText edit = (EditText)LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item);
edit.setHint(getItem(position).toString());
```

That will get the corresponding string as hint, instead of text.

Comment: yes i know that, but its not an ordinary EditText, it is in a Navigation Drawer (if i open it again the string array tekst is shown)

Comment: I don't understand. An `EditText` is the same everywhere, even in a navigation drawer.

Comment: I get my Text from an String array in values/strings.xml, this is being added to the listview through an ArrayAdapter. however if i open up the listview the edit texts are filled with the String array as tekst, so not as Hints which i want them to be.

Comment: i've added an image of the current result, what i want is those things to be hints and not text, so when i press the editText the text disappears when i start typing.

Comment: This also doesn't work, gives me a class cast exception, from android.support.v5.widget.Drawerlayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText